# Beginner's Guide to Persistent Homology (focusing on Theoretical Mathematical Aspects)

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, topological-data-analysis

I am interested in seeking out a reference for learning Persistence Homology (more of the theoretical mathematical aspects rather than the applications/ computer science aspects).

Currently, the two books I have attempted to read:

- *Elementary Applied Topology* by R. Ghrist (Not very elementary at all)
- *Computational Topology - An Introduction* by Herbert Edelsbrunner (also not an easy read)

One issue I faced reading the above two books is that the format of the books is like a story or "novel", rather than the theorem/proof style which is more organized. Also, the level of the books are quite difficult (despite the words "elementary" and "introduction").

Does anyone know a more gentle introduction to the subject of persistent homology? Ideally a self-contained book would be good.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having trouble resolving the tension between you wanting a reference for *beginners* but also a reference *focusing on theoretical math*. The *beginner* bit makes me want to recommend something like

- [Persistent Homology: A Non-Mathy Introduction with Examples](https://towardsdatascience.com/persistent-homology-with-examples-1974d4b9c3d0)

or any of the various other blog posts or YouTube videos giving an intuitive description of persistent homology. But since you want theoretical math:

- [Persistence Theory: From Quiver Representations to Data Analysis by Steve Oudot](https://geometrica.saclay.inria.fr/team/Steve.Oudot/books/o-pt-fqrtda-15/surv-209.pdf) – An survey book that treats the algebraic aspect and topological aspect of persistent homology separately. I like what I've read from it so far.
- [Topological Pattern Recognition for Point Cloud Data by Gunnar Carlsson](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/BB0DA0F0EBD79809C563AF80B555A23C/S0962492914000051a.pdf/topological_pattern_recognition_for_point_cloud_data.pdf) – This is kinda like a fundamental paper in the field, but Carlsson does provide a nice exposition.

And I should really also link to this [analogous question over on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/310384/64073).